# Multi Select Drag/Drop Infragistics Ignite UI Tree

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, infragistics, ignite-ui, igtree

I am using the below Infragistics plugin.
http://www.igniteui.com/tree/api-and-events

I am able to select a node drag and drop. But I am not able to select multiple nodes at a time and drag and drop to another node/folder. Is there any configuration to achieve this which I am missing?

Thanks,
Krishna Prasad

Answer (score 0):

The `igTree` does not support multiple node dragging and dropping. However when a node is dragged and dropped it will also move all of its children. You can enable the checkboxes feature if you want to allow your end-users to select multiple nodes in the tree, but they won't be able to drag and drop them all together.